# How update main menu in SugarCRM 7.2

Tags: git, menu, sugarcrm

I have SugarCrm in git. That sugar repo has new custom modules.
When i checkout that repo from git and run sugar, all functionally is worked. But i didn`t see new module in main menu.

If i go by URL:
http://sugar.loc/#MY_Module
then i get perfect work of my module.

I did "Repair and Rebuild" and clear cache folder, but it not helped me.

For some project me helped action "Repair Config", but not for all (((

PS: DB is backup from original sugar(to which was installed custom module)

Please help, can someone knows how to solve it

With respect Aleksey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure it has been enabled in the  "Display Modules and Subpanels"-page found in the Administration area